# Smooth surface Plot with Pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My question is almost similar to this on:
[smoothing surface plot from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848740/smoothing-surface-plot-from-matrix)

only that my toolset is matplotlib and numpy (so far).

I have sucessfully generated a X, Y and Z-grid to plot
with

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='summer', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpa=None)
```

However, as the values are quite jumpy, it looks terribly.
[image: Exampleplot - terribly edgy, ugly... not usable and stuff]

I'd like to smoothen things up, make at least the vertices connected, or look like that.

My data is generated like that:
I have a function

```
svOfMatrix(x, y)
```

which produces a matrix in dependence on x, calculates its y-th power, selects a subset of columns and rows, and calculates the maximum singular value.
So, Z[x,y] is svOfMatrix(x, y)

As this calculation is quite expensive, I don't want to make the steps for x too small, and Y is bound to be integer 
Further, even for very small steps, there might be quite some changes, I don't want see. So I'd like to interpolate it somehow.
I found
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html
but I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the link you suggested, the example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#two-dimensional-spline-representation-procedural-bisplrep) is probably closest to what you want. You can use the example with your values,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:20j, -1:1:20j]
Z = (X+Y) * np.exp(-6.0*(X*X+Y*Y)) + np.random.rand(X.shape[0])

xnew, ynew = np.mgrid[-1:1:80j, -1:1:80j]
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X, Y, Z, s=0)
znew = interpolate.bisplev(xnew[:,0], ynew[0,:], tck)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='summer', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=None)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xnew, ynew, znew, cmap='summer', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=None, antialiased=True)
plt.show()
```

Also, `antialiased=True` may make it look better but I think is on by default. The first plot looks like this,

[image]

and the smoothed plot like this,

[image]

The problem with your the low frequency noise in your data is that it will be difficult to define a grid fine enough to resolve. You can adjust the level of smoothing with the `s` argument to `interpolate.bisplrep` or perhaps coarse grain/filter your data to leave only major trends (e.g. using [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html) if you have regular gridded data). Alternatively, consider a different type of plot such as pcolormesh as the data is essentially 2D.

Comment: Thank you. If I rebuild your example, it works. With my data how ever, the plot looks completely strange. I guess something with my data is odd. Therefore I settel with the 2-d pcolormesh, as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the data_frame into this function. You'll get a proper smoothen surface plot. Incase you face any error, just choose only those features from data_frame which are numerical.

> 'data_frame = data_frame.select_dtypes(include='number')'

```
    from scipy import interpolate
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

    def surface(data_frame, title=None, title_x=0.5, title_y=0.9):

        X, Y = np.mgrid[-10:10:complex(0,data_frame.shape[0]), 
    -10:10:complex(0,data_frame.shape[1])]
        Z = data_frame.values

        xnew, ynew = np.mgrid[-1:1:80j, -1:1:80j]
        tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X, Y, Z, s=0)
        znew = interpolate.bisplev(xnew[:,0], ynew[0,:], tck)

        fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=znew)])
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark', 
                          width=800, 
                          height=800,
                          title = title,
                          title_x = title_x, 
                          title_y = title_y
                         )
        return fig
```