# Scipy.interpolate and a 3D surface in matplotlib - data seems to be rotated within the axes?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm having trouble understanding a strange side effect of interpolating my data. I am plotting a 2D surface onto a 3D grid, this part works fine, however as soon as I tweaked it to include scipy.interpolate I get a strange glitch, (at least I think it is a glitch).

Below is an image of two plots, LHS is the original data, RHS the interpolated plot. As you can see I have rotated the RHS so that the similarities between the shapes are clear, but as a result the axis facing us is different;

[image: On the left we see the original data, on the right the strangely interpolated data]
(I have rotated both of these extensively and I'm confident the symmetry in this view is not a coincidence, it looks too similar and they look too different when viewed at the same rotation)

To add interpolation to my code I followed the answer to this question:
[Smooth surface Plot with Pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157650/smooth-surface-plot-with-pyplot)

I'll also add my code before and after I added that bit, in the hope that there's something really obvious I've missed

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#y is the sin(beta-alpha) value, x is the tan(beta) value and z is the cross-section in fb
y = np.array(Y_list)
x = np.array(x_list)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zs = np.array(z_list)
Z = zs.reshape(Y.shape)
print(type(Z))
print(Z.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.ylabel(r"$Sin(\beta - \alpha)$")
plt.xlabel(r"$Tan(\beta)$")

ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)  # disable automatic rotation
ax.set_zlabel('Cross-section (pb)', rotation=90)

#this is the rotation bit
for angle in range(0, 360):
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
```

(Obviously there is code beforehand importing everything such as numpy, scipy etc and getting the data, but this is untouched between the two versions)

```
y = np.array(Y_list)
x = np.array(x_list)

xstart = float(x[0])
xend = float(x[-1])
ystart = float(y[0])
yend = float(y[-1])
X, Y = np.mgrid[xstart:xend:10j, ystart:yend:22j]

zs = np.array(z_list)
#Z = zs.reshape(Y.shape)

#The following lines perform interpolation
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X, Y, zs, s=0)
Znew = interpolate.bisplev(X[:,0], Y[0,:], tck)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.ylabel(r"$Sin(\beta - \alpha)$")
plt.xlabel(r"$Tan(\beta)$")

ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)  # disable automatic rotation
ax.set_zlabel('Cross-section (pb)', rotation=90)

#this is the rotation bit
for angle in range(0, 360):
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
```

I'm stumped and any help would be appreciated!